# Illustrator: how to select or delete all raster objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections, raster

I'm about to submit some illustrations and they should not contain any raster effect or image and the illustration objects are too complex. I don't know where I used the effects or raster objects.

Is there a way to find all objects with that specifics in artboard and within clipping masks, groups and such and delete them?

Comment: No, a tool like this could be made but it would have hard time with all possible effects from third parties. Also it depends on what you output to as sometimes the export itself will trigger the rasterization even if its not raster in illustrator. Oh and what is too complex? 100 objects 1000 objects 10000 objects or like the drawing i have now up has 2 million objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that raster images appear in "Links panel", could be selected from there, then by clicking "Goto link" the raster object will selected in artboard and then could be deleted.